# Can't access localhost/phpmyadmin - #1146 - Table 'phpmyadmin.pma_column_info' doesn't exist

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp

so iv'e been deleting some old database in my phpmyadmin then when i access localhost/phpmyadmin again it says Error

## 1146 - Table 'phpmyadmin.pma_column_info' doesn't exist

[image]

can anyone help me how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

In `config.inc.php` you have defined a database and tables for the [phpMyAdmin configuration storage](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#phpmyadmin-configuration-storage) which enables additional features. Since you've removed one of those tables, you're getting the error when phpMyAdmin tries to use it.

First, edit your `config.inc.php` to either remove or comment out the line mentioning `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['column_info']`. That should allow you to log in (unless you removed more tables, in which case you might want to just comment out the whole block, including the pmadb directive). Once you're logged in, you can either modify and import the file `create_tables.sql` from the sql directory or just be happy without those features.

To disable the features entirely, just comment out or remove that portion of your configuration file; there's no harm to be done there, only features (such as bookmarks or the central column feature) that won't work.